# Accessing loose files from Windows Installer

Tags: installation, zip

I've built a .msi Installer which has some 'loose files' ie files not in the .msi
For simplicity, assume I have:

- Installer.msi
- AFile.txt

It works fine if run from a regular folder that contains the Installer + loose file.

But if its from a Zipped folder (Archive.zip), Windows quietly unzips to a Temp folder before running the .msi installer.  The installer then can't find the loose files its looking for because its being run from some random place in the Temp folder.  I get an error:

**Source file not found:**

**C:\Users\testing\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_Archive.zip\AFile.txt**

Is there any way of building an Installer that can determine where its been unpacked to?  Or somehow say the loose file is in the same folder as the .msi?

Comment: If contents of ZIP are not extracted completely (and they are not in your case), you just don't have those other files, and MSI complains correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I understand the loose file has not been extracted to the Temp folder.  Is there no way of having loose files and being able to run from a Zip folder?

Comment: Nothing is "run from Zip folder". There's no such thing as Zip folder - this is only custom representation of the ZIP file, and for any operations files are extracted to temporary place. Windows doesn't mount ZIPs as folders or disks.